# Redis Cluster mode slower than Standalone

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, redis, cluster-computing, database-performance

I've a Redis Cluster of 3 master nodes version 3.0.3 hosted on 3 EC2 t2.medium instances. When I sit on a 4th instance to measure the SET, GET performance using `redis-benchmark`, I have

```
$ redis-benchmark -h redis-com-01 -p 6379 -t set,get -n 1000000
====== SET ======
...
33550.29 requests per second

====== GET ======
...
32353.04 requests per second

$ redis-benchmark -h redis-com-02 -p 6379 -t set,get -n 1000000
====== SET ======
...
36329.29 requests per second

====== GET ======
...
37199.61 requests per second

$ redis-benchmark -h redis-com-03 -p 6379 -t set,get -n 1000000
====== SET ======
...
32338.39 requests per second

====== GET ======
...
32169.86 requests per second
```

But, when I use the benchmark tool `simple.py` from https://github.com/Grokzen/redis-py-cluster to measure the SET, GET performance of a whole Cluster, I'm quite surprise with the result

```
$ python simple.py --host redis-com-03 --port 6379 --timeit
10k SET/GET operations took: 4.3375210762 seconds... 2305.46430192 operations per second
20k SET/GET operations took: 8.5704600811 seconds... 2333.59700772 operations per second
40k SET/GET operations took: 17.3284561634 seconds... 2308.34181781 operations per second
```

I've already followed the checklist http://redis.io/topics/latency. All the nodes are configured with AOF, fsync every second.
The difference in write performance is inexplicable for me. Could someone give me a clue why and if it's possible how to fix this? Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK `simple.py` is just a busy look, does not use multiple threads to saturate the server. The reality is that we need a cluster aware `redis-benchmark`, and I need to do it ASAP... For now it is very hard to evaluate the total performance of a Redis Cluster, but while not identical, the performance of each node is very similar to the one of a stand alone node.

Note that making `redis-benchmark` threaded and able to test multiple nodes at the same time is just a first step. In order to test a big benchmark what is needed is also to run the benchmark in parallel in multiple different nodes and sum the results.

Comment: Thanks to your advice, I just tried to stress this cluster using 64 processes and the total performance is ~42k ops/s. When I added 1 more node to generate the load (always using 64 processes/node) the total performance is ~75k ops/s.

Comment: That's good, you are still not seeing the full performance probably since 64 processes in Python burn a considerable amount of CPU to execute instead of producing load. The sooner I provide `redis-benchmark` which is cluster aware, the better. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

That script i created is not something that can be compared with redis-benchmark. The primary use of that script is to do a simple performance check of the client side code to see where it uses the most time and where slow parts of the code is.

If i remember correctly, the main slowdown in the python code is the crc16 calculation that is done on each key. And i think that you should see about 50% performance drop compared to a standalone redis node because of all the extra work that has to be done on the client side.

Comment: Thanks for your note!

Comment: // , Good tip. Looks like a good Python benchmarker would benefit from something like https://pypi.python.org/pypi/crcmod, then, I guess.